# Two forms, one select/dropdown box - need to copy select value from one form to other

Tags: javascript, select, copy

I have a scenario where a visitor can select a value from a drop-down box, and then choose select one of two submit buttons [that trigger two different form actions and are both in separate  elements].

The drop-down box is relevant for both submit buttons, however, is only under one of the  element.

I've tried a write a javascript function that pulls the drop-down value from one form element to the other, but it doesn't seem to work. PLease see my code below, any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function grabselection(){
var select_genre = document.getElementById("genre");
var genre = select_genre.value;
var genre_cloaked = document.getElementById("genre2");
genre_cloaked.value = genre;
}
</script>


<form class="youtubeupload" action="uploadfinalised.php" method="post"      enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="token" type="hidden" value="Alhl"/>
<select  id="genre2" class="genre" name="genre"><option value="">What style is your video?</option></select>
<input value="" onclick="grabselection();" type="submit" id="uploadbutton" /></div>
    </form>     

<form id="provideurl" class="provideurl" method="post" action="provideurl.php">
<select id="genre" class="genre" name="genre">
    <option value="">What style is your video?</option>             
    <option id="genreid_1" value="1">first genre</option>
    <option id="genreid_2" value="2">second genre</option>
    <option id="genreid_3" value="3">third genre</option>
    <option id="genreid_4" value="4">fourth genre</option>  
</select>
```

I am sure there is a simpler solution to this - linking one form element to two different forms, but I'm not sure how to do it - any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the value on the `genre2` select box but **it doesn't contain any options with that value**. To accomplish what you're trying to achieve, the options would have to be defined in *both* select fields.

Why don't you just use a hidden input and update the value on that?

```
<input type="hidden" name="genre2" />
```

Arguably the best thing to do would be to **determine the form action based on user input** so that you only have 1 form... there's a brief discussion here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-action.phtml

Comment: I've just discovered another issue - I can't seem to pull the value on the action page using $_POST['genre'];- The value appears to be blank?!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following code to take the value of the selected index -

```
var genre = select_genre.value;
```

Instead, change that line of code to -

```
var genre = select_genre.options[select_genre.selectedIndex].value;
```

This will insert the value of current selection into genre variable. The rest of the code should work fine. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I don't think that this matters as `grabselection()` is only invoked **after** the form has been submitted, at which point the select itself has a value.